# Can I get TCP window size for current connection before I send data with Linux API send or sendto

Tags: linux

Is there Linux API available that I can retrieve TCP window size for current TCP connection before I send data with Linux API send or sendto?

The reason I need this is if current TCP window size is less than the length of data I need to send, I can release CPU manually and do something else in other threads or processes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a better method but, actuallly, only the use of a `RAW SOCKET` comes in my mind.

Handling data at transport layer allows you to access to TCP header (and then the `window` 16 bit field).

The counterpart is that you have to handle TCP stack between you and the peer, that is a bit crazy and laborious.

This is an example about what you need to do in order to **JUST** send a SYN to a host. Avoid the final loop, otherwise it starts a syn-flood attack against your peer :)

[TCP with RAW SOCKETS](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-sockets-c-code-linux/)